# Dictionary to histogram plot in seaborn/plotly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Hi guys i want to plot histogram in seaborn from dictionary data

```py
{'C873-': 15, 'C860T': 16, 'A1860-': 17, 'A1878-': 17, 'C652T': 20, 'G372-': 33, 'C2107T': 37, '-447A': 144}
```

there is couple of threads with similar questions but they are saying that bar plot is better or given answers don't work as they shoudl. I need to plot this as histogram

what i was trying to do is

```py
plt.hist([i[-1] for i in sum_dict],  bins=len(sum_dict), color='g')
plt.show()
```

but this looks awful, is in plotly and probably  is wrong

Im not stubborn to use seaborn so i will check out everything

Comment: I'm not clear on what are you trying to achieve. What are the contents of the `sum_dict`?

Comment: Are you sure you want a histogram and not a bar plot?

Comment: Why do you have to plot this as a histogram? A histogram of n values in n bins is called a bar plot, even more so, since your x-values are categorical data.

Comment: @LemurPwned i posted values of sum dict, As i said i need to plot this data as histogram becouse that is my task. This dict is made from list of string so if ploting from dict is a trouble i we can plot this from list

Comment: @newDev2000 if that's the case, then the above suggestions are correct -- you should use `plt.bar` over `plt.hist` since you already have the value counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should want to use `plt.bar` instead of `plt.hist`, since you already have the counts of each value (it's still a histogram though).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = {
    'C873-': 15,
    'C860T': 16,
    'A1860-': 17,
    'A1878-': 17,
    'C652T': 20,
    'G372-': 33,
    'C2107T': 37,
    '-447A': 144
}

ind = np.arange(len(data))

plt.bar(ind, list(data.values()))
plt.xticks(ind, list(data.keys()))
plt.show()
```

One cool thing is that you may use the seaborn colour palette along with the code above, simply by passing a colour range generated by `sns.color_palette` to `plt.bar` function's `color` argument:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = {
...
}

ind = np.arange(len(data))
palette = sns.color_palette("husl", len(data))

plt.bar(ind, list(data.values()), color=palette)
plt.xticks(ind, list(data.keys()))
plt.show()
```

And the final result:
[image]

Comment: Why not immediately `sns.barplot(x=list(data.keys()), y=list(data.values()))`? Or  `plt.bar(x=list(data.keys()), y=list(data.values()))` ?

Comment: @JohanC that's a fair point -- this can be done in fewer lines of code.

Comment: can we make range that goes in increments of 5 rather than 20

Comment: @newDev2000, sure! that's pretty easy, just add `plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 150, 5))`